# Что лучше: метод класса или метод расширения

Tags: asp.net-mvc, архитектура

Добрый день.
Я начинающий программист, поэтому могут возникать глупые вопросы.
Делаю проект на ASP.MVC, возник вопрос связанный с архитектурой проекта.
У меня есть класс ViewModel, в котором содержатся данные, с которыми будет работать контроллер и которые будут выводиться на интернет-страницей. Есть класс ViewModelBuilder, который преобразует объект базы данных во ViewModel и наоборот.
Мне нужно  принять строку, введенную пользователем, обработать ее, вытянуть недостающие данные из интернета и сформировать ViewModel.
Возник вопрос, в какой класс написать методы, обрабатывающие входные данные (это не валидация), вытягивающие их сети недостающие данные  и формирующие ViewModel.

Варианта у меня 3:
- В контроллер
- В ViewModel
- В отдельный класс расширения к ViewModel.
Идея с контроллером мне не нравится, так как эти методы все-таки BusinessLayer и в контроллере им делать особо нечего.
ViewModel  почему-то тоже не хочется грузить этими методами. Вроде бы как они будут логично смотреться в этом классе, но почему-то на уровне интуиции, мне эта идея не нравится.
Вынести их в класс расширения я боюсь за производительность.

Вопрос: где правильно с точки зрения архитектуры и следования принципам MVC разместить методы, которые обрабатывают строку, введенную  пользователем, преобразуют ее, вытягивают из сети данные и  преобразуют их для записи в свойства ViewModel.

Comment: почему вынос в класс расширения должен сказаться на производительности?

Comment: Все-таки метод другого класса. Я не настолько хорошо разбираюсь в низкоуровневых процессах, чтобы четко понимать этот вопрос.

Comment: А вы не бойтесь. Страх идёт от незнания. Почитайте, как реализуются методы расширения, это ведь лишь синтаксический сахар. И, право, смешно бояться падения производительности на вызовах методов расширения, когда у вас есть чтение из БД и параметры интернета:  эти операции в десятки и сотни раз медленнее. Вы боитесь, но там экономия на спичках.

Comment: @AK, стоит оформить ответом :-)

Comment: @AK : Вопрос с опасениями за производительность сняли. Я понимаю, что у меня с производительностью и так мрак и кошмар, поэтому не хотел еще дополнительно усугублять. Но вопрос с архитектурой остался. Я правильно Вас понял, что размещение методов во ViewModel и в классе расширения - равноценны с точки зрения архитектуры?

Comment: @Grundy в метро неудобно код писать. Доехал, подумал, есть ли мне ещё что добавить -- и да, вышло на полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вижу в вашем вопросе два слоя.

Первый -- про производительность методов расширения. По факту, это всего лишь [синтаксический сахар для вызова статического метода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). Когда компилятор встречает инструкцию вызыва экстеншена -- он генерирует IL-код вызывающий статический класс:

```
void Main()
{
    var message = "Hello Extension Methods";
    int counter1 = message.WordCount();
    int counter2 = MyExtensions.WordCount(message);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

IL-код одинаковый в обоих случаях:

[image: IL for static]

Вы переживаете о возможном падении производительности. Но у вас в приложении есть чтение из БД и парсинг интернета -- намного более долгие операции, в десятки и сотни раз. Вы боитесь потерять, но там экономия на спичках.

Второй слой вопроса -- где размещать правильно. Я бы хотел ответить вам в терминах DDD (Domain-driven design): там где у вас находится слой, который называется предметная область.

Вот у вас собственно описание этого класса:

> Мне нужно принять строку, введенную пользователем, обработать ее (и это не валидация),
>   вытянуть недостающие данные из интернета и сформировать ViewModel.

Я не знаю вашу предметную область, поэтому могу предложить назвать этот класс *Manager. Это не очень правильно с точки DDD и подход можно критиковать, но архитектурно -- движение в более правильную сторону, всяко лучше чем размещать метод на контроллере (архитектура ТТУК (Толстый тупой уродливый контроллер)) и тем более выносить [бизнес-логику] в слой представления.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Не вижу смысла создавать отдельный вопрос , принцип один и тот же , что и у автора данного , прошу просто уточнить , правильно ли я понял суть проблемы ...  
Получается что для обработки пользовательских данных в MVC правильнее всего создать отдельный класс  , или несколько доп классов  , отвечающих за разные задачи , и для каких то расчетов с пользовательскими данными или каких то логических операции , дебетовых кредитовых и тд и тп , вызывать из контроллера методы или функции этих дополнительных классов . В принципе как мог , спросил ...Тоже пока мониторю эту тему и пробую понемногу ...

Comment: @Eikhner "Обработка пользовательских данных" -- это что, валидация или бизнес-логика? Вопрос у вас может оказаться весьма далёким от постановленного в этой задаче. Пока могу просто сказать из общих соображений, что "контроллеры должны быть тонкими, модели -- толстыми, а представления -- тупыми" (С)

Comment: @A K Не валидация , "для каких то расчетов с пользовательскими данными или каких то логических операции , дебетовых кредитовых и тд и тп "

Comment: @Eikhner В domain однозначно. Много примеров на банковские счета есть в книге у Эрика Эванса.

Comment: @A K , спасибо ,  "контроллеры должны быть тонкими, модели -- толстыми, а представления -- тупыми" (С), буду пробовать ...